# Wordpress, PodCMS and Search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, content-management-system, podscms

I have a WordPress site for a client. He owns a video store, and I made a site for him to update the list of movies, usually just the "new this week" movies.

I used PodCMS as an easy way for him to upload movies and then display them. No need for him to even create posts. Works really well, it's a great extension, I'm just having some issues.

The Pod has a field where you insert the release date. 2010-04-20
Then there is a Pod page/template combo that calls the movies with a certain release date like this:
`$date = pods_url_variable('last');`
He then just creates a blank WP page with the slug 2010-04-20
So when you open that page, the Pod page/template reads that slug and renders a list of the appropriate movies.

My problem:
I need these to be searchable. Is this possible.

I'm also open to suggestions on other ways to go about making this site work. I need it to be as simple as that. Uploads some movies and creates a new page. Then the rest is done automatically.

Answer (score 2):

A PodsCMS search is nothing more than a mySQL table search for the search term. You can search the title, body, pretty much anything. Here's an example:

*Note: I'm using "whatever" as the pod info. I'm also forming a string that goes into the $where position which comprises the various pods variables I want to search on. Also, I'm assuming pagination using the Pods pagination controls but I want that variable carried across the pages so I can offset.*

```
<?php

$search_term = $_GET["s"];
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
$page_number = $_GET['pg'];

?>

<h1>
      Results for "<?php echo $search_term; ?>"<?php if($page_number > 1){ ?> (Continued)<?php } ?><?php if($paged > 1){ ?> (Continued)<?php } ?>
  </h1>

  <?php if($paged <= 1){ ?>
  <h2>Results in Whatever...</h2>

      <?php
            $whateverSentence = "(t.name LIKE '%" .$search_term. "%') || (t.whatever LIKE '%" .$search_term. "%')";
            $whatever = new Pod('whatever');
            $whatever->findRecords($orderby = 't.whatever DESC', $rows_per_page = 5, $where = $whateverSentence, $sql = null);
            $total_whatever = $whatever->getTotalRows();
      ?>
      <?php if( $total_whatever >0 ) : ?>
      <?php while ( $whatever->fetchRecord() ) : ?>
      <?php
            // Set Variables
            $whatever_ID = $whatever->get_field('id');
            $whatever_Permalink = $whatever->get_field('slug');
            $whatever_Name = $whatever->get_field('name');

    ?>

Code that echos the pods variables and represents the search result

<?php endwhile ?>

<?php else: ?>

<p>Sorry, no results found for that search.</p>

<?php endelse; endif ?>
<?php echo $whatever->getPagination($label = '<span class="pagination-text">Go to page:</span>'); ?>


<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need the WordPress page content - the list of movies - to be searchable?

WP doesn't search pages natively, but will with [WordPress › Search Everything « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/) and search better with [WordPress › Relevanssi « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/)